# Insert Layouts dynamically into an activity at runtime

Tags: android, xml, layout

I need to dynamically add a 'template' layout to my activity at runtime based on the click of a button.

Shown in the code block below is a simplified version of my layout. The contents of HEADER C (i.e. BODY C1, BODY C2 ... BODY Cn) are the components that need to be added at runtime. They are all of the same format and are defined in a separate xml file with a relative layout. How do I accomplish this task? I have tried a LayoutInflater, but was unsuccessful. Does LayoutInflater require a LinearLayout to inflate?

```
<SCROLLVIEW>
   <RELATIVE_LAYOUT>
      ____________
      HEADER A
         ____________
         BODY A
   </RELATIVE_LAYOUT>
   <RELATIVE_LAYOUT>
      ____________
      HEADER B
       ____________
    BODY B
</RELATIVE_LAYOUT>
<RELATIVE_LAYOUT>
____________
HEADER C
    ____________
    BODY C1
    ____________
    BODY C2
    .
    .
    .
    ____________
    BODY Cn
<RELATIVE_LAYOUT>
</SCROLLVIEW>
```

Thanks, any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: paste code of inflating and adding layout here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    LinearLayout Parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

    View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main_new,null);
    Parent.addView(child);
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
View headerView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.class_name, null);
```

to inflate your layout.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**rootView represent the RelativeLayout*/
View headerView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflater(R.layout.header_view, rootView, false);
rootView.add(headerView);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like so:

```
general = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.general_tab);  // get the id of the layout you wish to add your view to
TextView programs = new TextView(this); // create a new view/widget to add
programs.setText("Program(s): " + prgdisp);  // set the text 
general.addView(programs);  // add the new view/widget to the existing layout
```

**EDIT**

I missed that you had an xml layout for it already.  Change the above to:

```
general = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.general_tab);  // get the id of the layout you wish to add your view to
View header = View.inflate(this, R.layout.class_name, null); // inflate your layout
general.addView(header);  // add the new view/widget to the existing layout
```